# How to set cursor positioned on focused Entry tag in XAML?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I tried using the CursorPosition value but it doesn't appear to be working. The value is a single digit and the cursor needs to update to be in front of the digit when the value is tapped (or focused upon). Anyone know what might be the issue here?

```
    public PaymentOccurrencesControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        PaymentNumberEntry.Focused += PaymentEntryField_Focused;
    }

    private void PaymentEntryField_Focused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            PaymentNumberEntry.Focused += (s, e) =>
            {
                PaymentNumberEntry.CursorPosition = 1;
            };
        });
    }
```

Comment: "doesn't appear to be working" - this is not a helpful description of the problem.  Please show us the code that you've tried and describe what it is or isn't doing when executed.

Comment: good idea - added a screenshot link.

Comment: I'd guess that hardcoding the `CursorPosition` in the XAML isn't helpful, because that property will be evaluated **before** the binding is evaluated, when the `Entry` is empty.  You probably need to set it in code after the binding has been evaluated.

Comment: and please do not post code or errors as images, that is against site rules

Comment: my apologies - added a code snippet to my post with what I currently have; still troubleshooting

Comment: The MainThread call should be inside the event handler

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the code that sets CursorPosition in:

```cs
   Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread( () => {
       …
    });
```

This delays the cursor change until *after* xamarin and the phone’s OS have completed the focus action - which sets cursor position, overriding what you did.

---

ONLY wrap the line that sets cursor position:

```cs
public PaymentOccurrencesControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    PaymentNumberEntry.Focused += (s, e) =>
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            PaymentNumberEntry.CursorPosition = 1;
        };
    });
}
```

Explanation: When the control gains focus, Android will begin executing your code after `PaymentNumberEntry.Focused`. It sees `BeginInvoke`, which tells Android "delay what's in here, until the current UI action (the control gaining focus) finishes". It *queues* this action:

```cs
() =>
    {
        PaymentNumberEntry.CursorPosition = 1;
    };
```

This allows Android to do whatever it wants to CursorPosition (actually, to its **native control's** equivalent field). That's what makes the situation confusing - CursorPosition is not controlling the actual cursor position, until the *next* time it is given a value.

When it finishes, it returns to the MainThread loop, which looks for the next action to do. Which is your CursorPosition logic. Because *your* code runs *last*, it successfully updates Android's native cursor position.

Comment: I added my code snippet to my post, wrapping it in this. Still doesn't appear to work. Let me know if you see any issues with my code. thanks

Comment: I've added to my answer the complete code. Plus an explanation.